# Java Http - Post Header Content-Length

Tags: java, http

i have problems with my http-headers.
I need to send a post-request with an empty body and the header "Content-Length:0".  But this seems impossible, becauce i get this exception:

--org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present--

But when i do not include the header, there is no Content-Length header in the request and therefore i get 400: Bad Request.
I build this in Python too and there it works fine, but i can not make it work in java. Can you help me, please?

Here is my Code:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.addHeader(header..);
httpPost.addHeader(another header);
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Length","0");
httpPost.addHeader(another header);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

**EDIT:**

Solved the problem with the answer from @Beno Arakelyan.

Comment: FWIW, sending a Content-Type if you not send a request body doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Your comment is not helpful @Reschke. We could discuss this post (wich performs an action wich does not need a body), but it is not my api. I just have to use this api and i can not change it. If i could, i would change more than just this :D

Comment: Are you sure you need to send Content-Length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to send the `Content-Length` with [http-request](https://github.com/jsunsoftware/http-request) which built on apache http client. It works fine. Example:

```
private static final HttpRequest<?> HTTP_REQUEST =
      HttpRequestBuilder.createGet(YOUR_URI)
        .addDefaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, "0")
        .build();

public void test(){
  System.out.println(HTTP_REQUEST.execute().getStatisCode()); // is 200
}
```

Comment: I will test it ;) Thanks for your input, i`ll give feedback

Comment: @TheJed Happy to help you

Comment: Is there any way to inspect the full request, so what is sended to the server? In my opinion this should work, but it fails also (as i mentioned i have a working python script, where i send a post request with my headers and a empty body and it works, so the error must be in my java - code). It did it exactly like you, just added the other headers in the same way.

Comment: Do you get the same error message? What request body/headers do you expect on your server? You can inspect full request by unit tests.

Comment: I debugged a bit and the request wich is going to the server as no headers (size = 0). Therefore i get again a 400 - Bad request. They are in the HTTP_REQUEST, but during the execute the module builds an org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder and request from this is going to the server, but without my headers. Are you sure that module works fine without a body?

Comment: Yes it is tested. Request body doesn't affect on headers.

Comment: @TheJed In my opinion the problem in a server. In the `http-request` there are tests which send headers and they are pass.

Comment: Your Code works, my bad. I forgot something by testing your example. Thanks a lot for your help, i was looking for something like this! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate the content length, the client will handle that for you. Try removing the header and set a body instead, for example: `httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(""))`.

Comment: already tried, but that does not work. The header is in that case not included :(

Answer (score 0):

This [Link directs you to the example below](https://reqbin.com/req/java/b3tqmhxa/post-request-with-content-length-header)

```
URL url = new URL("https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json");
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
http.setRequestMethod("POST");
http.setDoOutput(true);
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

String data = "{\"widget\": {\n    \"window\": {\n        \"title\": \"Sample Widget\",\n        \"name\": \"sample_widget\",\n        \"width\": 600,\n        \"height\": 400\n    },\n    \"image\": { \n        \"src\": \"images/test.png\",\n        \"name\": \"sample_test\",\n        \"hOffset\": 150,\n        \"vOffset\": 150,\n        \"alignment\": \"center\"\n    },\n    \"text\": {\n        \"data\": \"Click Here\",\n        \"size\": 36,\n        \"style\": \"bold\",\n        \"name\": \"sample_click\",\n        \"alignment\": \"center\"\n    }\n}} ";

byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
stream.write(out);

System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
http.disconnect();
```

Note: Content-Length will be added automatically.