# Karate - header name "Content-Length: 70" is automatically added for POST request while calling commonHeader in karate frameworkjs

Tags: karate

i m performing one POST request where i dont need "Content-Length" in headers as it is automatically assigned. And i have used "configure charset = null" in the code, still it is passing " Content-Length: 70" in the header.

please let me know how to remove  "Content-Length" from header ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. I know, you probably want to do a negative-test or something - but there is probably very little value in such a test. If you really want to do this, use a Java library for this particular scenario.

EDIT - or use cURL from Karate: [Is possible to execute curl in Karate tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64352517/143475)

Comment: thanks peter... if possible pls give one java example to remove header.. .thnks

Comment: try this - but I think this is very difficult in Java, I recommend just ignore this scenario - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49008027/143475

Comment: this is positvie sceario where still im not able to remove content length from headers